# What is the "man" called at the end of words like "chairman" or "sportsman" etc.?

Tags: terminology

What is the "man" called at the end of words like "chairman" or "sportsman" etc.? I thought it may be a suffix but that's a morpheme with no meaning on its own such as "ful" or "ly".

Comment: It is a suffix: -man https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/-man - See: https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/13091/words-ending-in-man-compound-or-suffix

Comment: Guess this is a duplicate query.

Comment: You could say ***man*** is a [head noun](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/head_noun) in contexts like *chairman, postman, drayman, delivery man*.